# submenu pure css and html disappears

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a menu which has a submenu. the submenu appears when i hover the main menu, but as soon as i try to go down to the submenu it disappears most of the time. Only if i'm very fast I'm able to get to it before it disappears.

HTML:

```
 <header>   
<div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#" id="logo" class="fl"><img src="images/logo.png" width="125" height="20" alt=""></a>
        <nav class="fl">
            <ul >
                <li> <a href="#" class="selected">Target Groups</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Manage Target Groups</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Create Target Group</a></li>
                </ul>   
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Activity</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- end .wrapper -->
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
header{
margin-top: 30px;
background: url(../images/header-bg.png) no-repeat; 
width: 942px;
height: 76px;
padding: 27px 25px 5px;
}
header .wrapper{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    float:left;
    width: 862px;
    padding: 0 40px 5px;        
    position:relative;
}
header nav{
    margin-left: 45px;          
}
header nav ul{
    z-index: 100;
}
header nav ul li{
    display: inline;    
    margin-right: 35px;
    line-height: 20px;
    z-index: 100;
}
header nav ul li ul{
    display: none;
    position:absolute;      
    width: 962px;
    left: 0;
    top: 40px;  
}

header nav ul li ul li{
    float: left;    
}

header nav ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;  
}
header nav ul li a{
    font-size:16px;
    color: #5b666a;
    text-decoration: none;  
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
header nav ul li a.selected,header nav ul li a:hover{
    background: #657073;
    color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

I'm really stuck, please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want, it's better to use `padding-top` for your submenu, instead of absolute positioning (with the latter you'll end up with 'empty' space between menu and submenu, causing mouseout):

http://jsfiddle.net/BAzx7/

EDIT: And I added `position:relative;` to `ul li`, and a lower `z-index` to `ul li ul`, otherwise the submenu would be over the main menu - and disable it...

http://jsfiddle.net/BAzx7/1/

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been banging my head over this for a few hours. You really helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

I've also fixed this with hoverIntent on one of my drop downs. Was an exclusive IE bug at the time but was a easy fix.

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

This is how my function looked.

```
    $('.main-nav > ul > li').hoverIntent({
        timeout: 300,
        over: function () {
            $(this).addClass('hover')
        },
        timeout: 300,
        out: function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hover')
        }
    });
```

My markup was in the same structure as the son of sucker fish menu.

Comment: I saw that solution somewhere, but I was aiming at pure css/html with no jquery. But thank you anyway.